# Bootstrap columns and button having unused space in the form

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

so it's my form:

```
    <form method="GET" action=".">
        <div class="container-fluid pt-2 px-5 py-3">
            <div class="row g-4">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-xl-6 py-xl-2">
                <div class="bg-secondary rounded h-25 p-4">
                    <h6 class="mb-3">Symbol</h6>
                    <select name="symbol" class="form-select form-select-sm mb-3" aria-label=".form-select-sm example">
                        <option value="">All Symbols</option>
                        {% for sym in used_symbols %}
                        <option value={{sym}}>{{sym}}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="bg-secondary rounded h-25 p-4 mt-2">
                    <h6 class="mb-3">Side</h6>
                    <select name="side" class="form-select form-select-sm mb-3" aria-label=".form-select-sm example">
                        <option value="">All</option>
                        <option value='l'>Long</option>
                        <option value='s'>Short</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="bg-secondary rounded h-25 p-4 mt-2">
                    <h6 class="mb-3">Status</h6>
                    <select name="status" class="form-select form-select-sm mb-3" aria-label=".form-select-sm example">
                        <option value="">All</option>
                        <option value='l'>Win</option>
                        <option value='s'>Loss</option>
                        <option value='s'>Draw</option>
                        <option value='s'>Open</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-xl-6 py-xl-2">
                <div class="bg-secondary rounded h-25 p-4">
                    <h6 class="mb-4">Check, Radio & Switch</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="bg-secondary rounded h-25 p-4 mt-2">
                    <h6 class="mb-4">Check, Radio & Switch</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="bg-secondary rounded h-25 p-4 mt-2">
                    <h6 class="mb-4">Check, Radio & Switch</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
        </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

but between the submit button and my two columns,there is so many unused spaces and I just wanted to remove them but every way I tried just didn't work...

I tried using style and giving height to the row or columns but it didn't solve the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the the `flex` or `grid`. If you specify `align-items` then you can control the height of row. I hope someone will enlighten us in the comments about why is it so.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">


<form method="GET" action=".">
  <div class="container-fluid pt-2 px-5 py-3">
    <div class="row g-4" style="align-items: start">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-xl-6 py-xl-2">
        <div class="bg-secondary rounded h-25 p-4">
          <h6 class="mb-3">Symbol</h6>
          <select name="symbol" class="form-select form-select-sm mb-3" aria-label=".form-select-sm example">
            <option value="">All Symbols</option>
            {% for sym in used_symbols %}
            <option value={{sym}}>{{sym}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-secondary rounded h-25 p-4 mt-2">
          <h6 class="mb-3">Side</h6>
          <select name="side" class="form-select form-select-sm mb-3" aria-label=".form-select-sm example">
            <option value="">All</option>
            <option value='l'>Long</option>
            <option value='s'>Short</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-secondary rounded h-25 p-4 mt-2">
          <h6 class="mb-3">Status</h6>
          <select name="status" class="form-select form-select-sm mb-3" aria-label=".form-select-sm example">
            <option value="">All</option>
            <option value='l'>Win</option>
            <option value='s'>Loss</option>
            <option value='s'>Draw</option>
            <option value='s'>Open</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-xl-6 pt-xl-2">
        <div class="bg-secondary rounded h-25 p-4">
          <h6 class="mb-4">Check, Radio & Switch</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-secondary rounded h-25 p-4 mt-2">
          <h6 class="mb-4">Check, Radio & Switch</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-secondary rounded h-25 p-4 mt-2">
          <h6 class="mb-4">Check, Radio & Switch</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```